# Parsing a Javascript Youtube Playlist (using Youtube API v3) into an Android Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, youtube-data-api

I'm currently trying to show one Youtube user playlist in my Android app but it's all a tough problem.

Anyway, I had an idea but I can not get it to work. It would be using a WebView and its loadDataWithBaseURL() method, so I can parse the actual html/javascript code to show the playlist, and then show it within the WebView. After trying to do it myself without success, I finally found this working code here on Stack Overflow:

```
<head>
<script>
        function load() {
            var playListID = "YOUR_PUBLIC_YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID";
            var requestOptions = {
                playlistId: playListID,
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 10
            };
            var apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
            gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
            gapi.client.load('youtube','v3', function () {  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list(requestOptions);
                                                            request.execute(function (data) { console.log (data) });
                                                        });

        }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

What I do is to store this code into a String and then I pass this String to the loadDataWithBaseURL() method like this:

`myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, code, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

Where **baseUrl** is "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/" and **code** is a String containing the html-javascript code mentioned above.

The problem that I'm having is that I don't see anything in myWebView, it keeps being blank. It doesn't load. Moreover, I'm trying to make this code work in a html file but when I open it with my browser, once again it doesn't load. The API and the Playlist Keys are set fine, so in advice I can say it's not the cause of the problem.

Thanks and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the mobile version of the YouTube website?

Comment: If you answered this question yourself, then type that into "your answer" and submit it, and then the question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after so many time trying to get this to work it seems that my mind was pretty confused. It finally was a lot simpler than that. I don't even know why I came up with the Javascript idea when, as I'm using a WebView, I can directly load the playlist's url with the loadUrl("http://youtube.com/USER_PLAYLIST...") method.